# IBM MobileFirst Operations Console error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

I am getting the following error on loading of MobileFirst Operations Console:
**angular-layer.min.js:98 GET https://mobilefoundation-ip-server.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/mfpconsole/services/management-apis/2.0/runtimes?fullInfo=true 500 (Internal Server Error)**
The Dashboard displays following error **"Server error. Contact the server administrator."**
Due to this the page is not loading properly.

[image]

Comment: Did this start recently? Or has it been this way since you provisioned the server?

Comment: I just setup the server and i started getting this error.

Comment: A few questions:
1. It seems that you created an instance of `Mobile Foundation service` from the Bluemix catalog - But, which  `Plan` ?

2. If the 'Plan' is other than developer, did you select `Start basic server` or did you choose the `Advanced` option?

3. If you chose the `Advanced` option, can you share the customization you supplied?

Comment: @PrashanthBhat i selected "Professional per capacity" plan with Start basic server. My colleague figured out that i had not created instance of DB2 on Cloud before adding the server. After this we created new instance of DB2 on cloud service and added it as an existing service. So now the error seems to be resolved. Thanks!